# ¿Como podría simplificar(acortar) estas funciones?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría poder simplicar las funciones de addEventListener y removeEvenListener tal como lo hace jquery.
Me gustaría logralode esta forma.

```
   // addEventListener
  $element.on('click', function(){});
  // removeEventListener
  $element.off('click', function(){});
```

Como lo logro sin necesidad de usar jquery.

Comment: ¿Y porque no quieres usar Jquery?

Comment: No entiendo bien, ¿acaso `el.addEventListener("click", eventHandler);` no  está ya simplificado en JavaScript? ¿Qué quieres lograr?

Comment: Por que es algo lento, y tarda en cargar un poco. Además de que pues me gustaría aprender javascript puro.

Comment: Lo que me gustaría lograr es, acortar esas funciones para no tener que agregar la función completa osea el.addEventListener y solo agregar el.on('ready')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Lo que me gustaría lograr es, acortar esas funciones para no tener que agregar la función completa osea el.addEventListener y solo agregar el.on('ready')

Te dejo un ejemplo bien simple. Pero, tener un "alias" para los metodos, nomas para "acortar" las funciones, puede "simplificar" tu programa/tu escritura, pero tendra el **nocivo efecto** de ser contra-intuitivo para cualquiera que agarre el codigo, cuando tu lo dejes.

Salu2

```js
// myJQuery
$ = function(selector) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  elem.on = elem.addEventListener;
  elem.off = elem.removeEventListener;
  
  return elem;
}

var element = $('div');

element.on('click', function manejador() {
  console.log('clickeado');
  element.innerHTML = "no va mas";
  element.off('click', manejador);  
})
```

```html
<div>click aqui</div>
```

Por los comentarios de @MarcosGallardo, hice esta version que usa `querySelectorAll` y aunque mas complicada funciona tanto con un elemento como con varios aunque tiene sus limitaciones.

```js
// myJQuery
$ = function(selector) {
  // Obtener un NodeList con los elementos
  var nl = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
  // Convertir como Array     
      na = [].slice.apply(nl);
  
  // si no encuentra hay nada
  if (na.length == 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  
  // si encuentra un solo elemento
  if (na.length == 1) {
    na[0].on = na[0].addEventListener;
    na[0].off = na[0].removeEventListener;
    
    return na[0];
  }

  // si encuentra varios
  var alias = { on: 'addEventListener', off: 'removeEventListener' };
  
  na.forEach(function(e) {
    Object.keys(alias).forEach(function(key, ix) {  
      e[key] = e[alias[key]] 
    })
  });
  
  Object.keys(alias).forEach(function(key, ix) {
    na[key] = function(...args) {
      na.forEach(function(e) {
        e[key](...args)
      });      
    }
  });
   
  return na;
}

// slector de elementos
var list = $('div');

list.on('click', function manejador(e) {
  console.log('clickeado');
  e.target.innerHTML = "no va mas";
  e.target.off('click', manejador);  
})

// selector de clases (aqui toma uno)
$('.otro').style.color = "red";

// selector de ID
$('#theone').style.background = "green";
$('#theone').style.color = "white";

// selectores multiples
$('.otro, #theone').forEach(function(e) {
  e.on('click', function(e) {
    e.target.style.color = "black";
    e.target.style.background = "initial";
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="theone">click aqui</div>
<div class="otro">quiza click aca</div>
```

Comment: @MarcosGallardo no hay niun problrma con la implementacion, no busca tomar todos los divs sino solo el primero ya que utiliza `querySelector`. Podria utilzarse `querySelectorAll` pero eso retorna un `NodeList` y deberia complicar el codigo y se perderia el ejemplo. Salu2

Comment: @MarcosGallardo edite la respuesta con una alternativa mas elaborada.

Answer (score 1):

> Lo que me gustaría lograr es, acortar esas funciones para no tener que agregar la función completa osea el.addEventListener y solo agregar el.on('ready')

Una forma `sencilla` de es extendiendo el `Element.prototype`. Por ejemplo:

```
// No funciona en IE7-
if (!Element.prototype.on) {
  Element.prototype.on = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
}
if (!Element.prototype.off) {
  Element.prototype.off = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
}
```

> Existen opiniones divididas sobre `extender las APIs nativas`, ya que si en un futuro los navegadores `implementan` funcionalidad sobre `on` y `off`, es probable que tu código deje de funcionar como esperabas.